# Passing data to broadcast authorization callback in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm new in Laravel broadcasting, currently I'm using 5.4. I want to update account dashboard which contain relevant post by their interest when somebody else create new post, I'm using private channel. I succeed to broadcast every new post which posted by another user in current logged user dashboard, I need to check if new post is relevant or not, if it is then broadcast if not, don't.

I think I can achieve with filtering in authorization event, inside `BroadcastServiceProvider` I have wrote.

```
public function boot(){
     Broadcast::routes();
     Broadcast::channel('discovery.post', function ($user) {
        return true;
     });
}
```

I've read documentation that we could pass data along with channel name such as

```
Broadcast::channel('discovery.post.{postId}', function ($user, $postId) {
    // get post category, tags, etc compare with user interest 
    return $isInterest;
});
```

But this approach must pass new post ID in laravel Echo as well

```
window.Echo.private('discovery.post.{how-i-get-this-id?}')
   .listen('NewPostDashboard', (data) => {
      // add new update to dom
   });
```

How I can solve this problem, I want keep my channel name `discovery.post`, I want send just to user with relevant interest, I need instance of Post to check if logged user is interest in this post.

Let me know if my question is unclear before vote me down. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: What was your solution to this?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this?